# When ordering off Amazon, are you allowed to keep a product that's significantly more valuable than what you originally ordered?

Tags: european-union, ecommerce

A friend of mine ordered a 60 EUR PC case off of Amazon.nl, but when receiving it today it turns out it is an entire prebuilt gaming PC valued at around 1400 EUR. in the friends group, we speculated that it's returned product that was processed improperly by Amazon as just the case instead of an entire PC. He powered it on to test if it's a functional computer and made it to the Windows 11 desktop, and from what I understand he's planning to set it aside for a couple months in case Amazon notices their mistake, but he's not planning on contacting Amazon to let them know about the wrong shipment.

I read [What to do if seller sends more than ordered?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/47077/what-to-do-if-seller-sends-more-than-ordered) and it talks about excess quantity, but I'm not entirely up to date on whether the Netherlands has a law like this or whether a potential law would cover a situation like this, and the other question doesn't really answer this and is also 5 years old, which might mean the law has changed. I also know that Amazon is such a massive company that they're unlikely to notice this mistake, and that even if they do they're likely to just write it off as shrinkage because of the sheer scale of business they do.

Speaking purely from a legal perspective, can my friend keep the PC while awaiting communication from Amazon, or is he legally required to contact Amazon himself and ask what he should do?

Comment: Essentially the same question as has been asked before in various ways: "may I keep something delivered to me by mistake?" or "can I keep refunds in error? etc. In a number of jurisdictions this is theft (or similar) if the receiver doesn't make a reasonable effort to tell the sender about the mistake. I don't know if someone has replied specifically about the Netherlands.

Comment: Leaving aside the question of whether the person who received the computer is in jeopardy of committing a crime under applicable law, **contacting the vendor / distributor about their error is the right thing to do**.  Moreover, even though acting in good faith does not always protect you from incurring legal liability, it usually *does* help mitigate any consequences.

Comment: "Asking for a friend." I see. ;-)

Comment: Memetically related: ["My husband ordered jewelry but motorcycle parts came instead..."](https://ifunny.co/picture/beware-of-a-new-amazon-scam-my-husband-ordered-me-7Q0IPPrk9)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I know how this sounds, but it genuinely is a friend, from the discord community of the Dutch tech site tweakers.net. At least, friend is the best way to describe him. It's an internet friend, so it's hard to really put a term on that.

Comment: @John Bollinger
I would disagree with the premise that it is "the right thing to do". Companies should be held financially liable for their own mistakes, you expending any amount of effort or resources to return the product is going right into that company's bottom line at your expense, and reducing the financial burden of that mistake on the company. Ultimately, this reduces the overal future quality of this service to other customers, even if only negligibly. 
I would argue **keeping** the PC if not contacted is the **morally right thing to do**.

Comment: @AnthonyKhodanian, you are welcome to your opinion, of course, but as far as I am concerned, it has nothing whatever to do with the entity  that suffered the inadvertent material loss being a company, as opposed to being an individual.  *Everyone* should expect to bear responsibility and possibly suffer consequences for their own mistakes. That has nothing to do with whether I, being beneficiary of or witness to such a mistake, have a moral obligation to do anything to help.  Many of our moral obligations do take the form of expending our own resources for others' benefit.

Comment: @John Bollinger Ah, I see where our differences lie then. You are of course entitled to your own opinion as well, but to me that is a *fundamental* distinction, that companies are not people and to treat them as such is harmful to society. Companies and consumers are in an antagonistic market relationship, while they can mutually benefit their goals are different. As such, to me, expending resources to help a person is almost always a morally good act, yet expending to help a company can range from morally good to morally evil, and in our present society leans heavily towards the latter end.

Answer (score 18):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

This is theft. Theft is defined at [Section 1 of the Theft Act 1968](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/60/section/1):

> A person is guilty of theft if he dishonestly appropriates property
> belonging to another with the intention of permanently depriving the
> other of it; and “thief” and “steal” shall be construed accordingly.

The word "appropriates" includes the following under [Section 3](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/60/section/3):

> Any assumption by a person of the rights of an owner amounts to an
> appropriation, and this includes, where he has come by the property
> (innocently or not) without stealing it, any later assumption of a
> right to it by keeping or dealing with it as owner.

The Act also elaborates on "intention of permenantly depriving the other of it" at [Section 6](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/60/section/6):

> (1) A person appropriating property belonging to another without
> meaning the other permanently to lose the thing itself is nevertheless
> to be regarded as having the intention of permanently depriving the
> other of it if his intention is to treat the thing as his own to
> dispose of regardless of the other’s rights; and a borrowing or
> lending of it may amount to so treating it if, but only if, the
> borrowing or lending is for a period and in circumstances making it
> equivalent to an outright taking or disposal.

This means that you commit theft the moment you make the decision to hold onto the item and see whether Amazon notices. As noted above, it doesn't matter whether you originally obtained it innocently, and it doesn't matter if you would give it back if you are caught. What matters is that you intend to keep it if you can get away with it.

This has been confirmed in *A-G's Reference (No 1 of 1983) [1984] 3 All ER 369* which was a case involving a bank payment made in error where the recipient kept quiet intending to keep the money if it wasn't noticed. I wrote another answer [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/58857/3066) where I provided more details.

### is he legally required to contact Amazon himself and ask what he should do?

From paragraph 189 of the above judgment:

> "there was a legal obligation upon the respondent to restore that
> value to the receiver when she found that the mistake had been made"

So yes, in this scenario you are required by law to contact the sender and inform them of the mistake.

Comment: That's the UK law. The OP is apparently in the Netherlands. Law differs between locales, and as the UK isn't even part of the EU, I don't see how UK law matters at all.

Comment: @JonWatte "Even if you supply a jurisdiction tag, we expect and encourage answers dealing with other jurisdictions – while it might not answer your question directly, your question will be here for others who may be from those jurisdictions." https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This hinges on the assumption that what OP received is a different item than what they ordered. A possible interpretation of what happened might be that this was a returned computer and Amazon decided that this is a PC case with some stuff inside but it is not worthwhile for them to figure out whether it works so they pretend it is just a case. In this interpretation Amazon shipped what they intended to ship. I don't know whether the argument would go through but in that case there would be no theft.

Comment: @quarague In your scenario it would fail the "property belonging to another" element, so it wouldn't be theft. However, the question was framed in terms of Amazon having made a "mistake", so my answer is aimed only at that scenario.

Comment: I think @quarague is closer to what happened. The speculation is that when this PC was returned to Amazon, it was mistakenly registered as a PC case, because it was returned inside the box and it's entirely possible that the warehouse employee who processed the return doesn't know enough about computers to know that this is a full PC and not just a case. Note that usually PCs are shipped inside the box the case was sold in, so the mistake is easy to make.

Comment: @Nzall That would still be theft. Just because Amazon didn't realise what they were doing doesn't mean it isn't still their property. quarague's scenario isn't theft because it involves Amazon *deliberately* deciding to give away the PC.

Comment: @quarague Well, Amazon certainly sent what they *intended* to send -- for a suitably wide interpretation of intention. In the end, some underpaid minion was specifically acting according to their instructions (e.g., storage id), training, and capabilities to put exactly that PC into exactly that posting package. Perhaps the scenario could be compared with buying some amateur painting at a flea market and then finding out that it is a valuable Rembrandt

Comment: In the case of Amazon, just tell their AI chatbot what happened and ask if you can keep it.

Comment: (Comment somewhat a joke, but has relevant law intersection given the case with the airline in Canada...)

Comment: @JonWatte I can't list as proof the laws of all jurisdictions on the face of the Earth to back it up but I'd be rather suprised to see one where this would be considered acceptable.

Answer (score 11):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Legally, you can treat unsolicited goods as a gift.  The relevant law is [39 U.S. Code § 3009 - Mailing of unordered merchandise](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/USCODE-2022-title39/pdf/USCODE-2022-title39-partIV-chap30-sec3009.pdf)
.  The FTC provides a [summary](https://consumer.ftc.gov/articles/what-do-if-youre-billed-things-you-never-got-or-you-get-unordered-products#unordered):

> By law, companies can’t send unordered merchandise to you, then demand payment. That means you never have to pay for things you get but didn’t order. You also don’t need to return unordered merchandise. You’re legally entitled to keep it as a free gift.

The motivation for this law is to prevent companies from mailing you unsolicited goods, then insisting the recipient must pay for them.

---

> Is he legally required to contact Amazon himself and ask what he should do?

As an aside, I'll note that Amazon's typical response to being asked what to do with accidental goods is, "just keep it."

Comment: "Legally, you can treat unsolicited goods as a gift" - only if the sender intended you to receive the unsolicited goods. https://law.stackexchange.com/a/21407/17893

Comment: Related, a couple received 120k from a bank by mistake and spent it. They went to jail: https://www.cnn.com/2019/09/09/us/bank-deposit-error-couple-spending-spree-trnd/index.html

Comment: This is US law. Apparently, the OP is in the Netherlands, which has a very different commercial code.

Comment: @JonWatte Right. US law and appropriately tagged accordingly.

Comment: This law prohibits such behavior *as a trade practice* - a company cannot build a business model by shipping more expensive items than what their customer ordered. A one-off shipping error is not a trade practice, I'm skeptical that you're legally entitled to solicit a shipment and keep any and all items that show up by mistake.

Comment: Amazon once processed a return order for an item that I had not asked to return and did not intend to return.  When I contacted them about the mistake, they indeed told me to just keep the money.  It wasn't as much as the value of the goods described in the question, but it was still significant.

Comment: This (sending you something cold and then demanding "payment") was apparently a scam going around in the 1970's. I remember commercials publicizing this law, with an Inuit gentleman flummoxed at getting a desk fan.

Comment: It may be interesting to note that, by in large, Amazon is a _shipping_ company, not a _retailer._ There are certainly exceptions, but the vast majority of what you buy on Amazon is not _theirs,_ but something they warehouse and ship on demand. It may help to look at their contract with their retailers, which probably states something like that the retailer is responsible for most or all costs in case of errors.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie IIRC (google's not being helpful), when netbooks first came out one major US online retailers shipping department sent a number of people cases of 5(?) laptops instead of just 1, and didn't catch the error quickly enough to recall all of the packages.  I remember reading that the only thing newegg was able to do to the people who refused to send the extras back was to ban their accounts because that law did apply.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Germany has a law explicitly about "receiving unsolicited goods" (BGB §241a), which also says you can keep them. However, it explicitly does *not* apply if the goods were sent or misdirected by mistake - so it would not apply here. Not sure how honest shipping mistakes are handled under US law.

Comment: @sleske Not sure about  §241a II. It says *"Gesetzliche Ansprüche sind nicht ausgeschlossen, wenn die Leistung **nicht für den Empfänger** bestimmt war oder in der **irrigen Vorstellung einer Bestellung** erfolgte..."*; in this case, the delivery **was** to the intended person; and there was **no erroneous presumption** of an order (it was clear what the friend ordered, and the seller tried to fulfill exactly that order but failed). A mere general mistake on the seller's side is their responsibility.

Comment: @sleske As an aside, §241a is a bit irregular because while the buyer can *keep* the wrong item (i.e. *possess/besitzen*), possibly permanently, they never acquire *property/Eigentum.* This may lead to a permanent split between possession and property which is a bit of an exception in the civil law and even raises constitutional questions. There is a lot of debate in any case how §241a aligns with other parts of the BGB and the general logical systematics which generally establish a right to repossess.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Well, arguably the "not intended for the recipient" in §241a also covers errors during packing - while the *package* was intended for the recipient, (some of) the *contentents* were not. I'm not sure how courts would see that, though.

Comment: My understanding of this is that they can't *charge* you for shipping the items back, but for incorrect items shipped to you, they can send you a pre-paid shipping label and require you to return it. It's the fundamental distinction for a number of Chinese product scams where you'll get the wrong item and they'll quote exorbitant shipping fees to return it (which there is a huge difference due to historical Chinese poverty influencing initial international postage rates). You don't have to pay those shipping rates, but they won't tell you that.

Comment: This doesn't apply in this case, but for low value items it really does cost Amazon more to have it shipped back and processed as a return than just writing it off and letting the customer keep it.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie "not a trade practice, a one-off" are you claiming Amazon has done this only once??   I doubt they have made any mistake only once.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm not suggesting it's happened exactly once, I'm suggesting that it is, in fact, a mistake. There is no intent to profit here, and no systematic framework by which this should purposefully happen again. Amazon isn't making their bottom line through shady shipping practices, they haven't even asked for payment. There's no reason to think this is some kind of anti-consumer scam, and it should not be treated as such under the law.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Well that's a good point. The unordered item scam is *all about* the demand for payment.

Answer (score 10):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

**tl;dr:** You must return goods sent by mistake when asked. You probably do not need to actively inform the sender.

---

### General consensus

According to the article *[Welche Rechte bestehen, wenn zu viel geliefert wurde?](https://www.onlinehaendler-news.de/e-recht/rechtsfragen/132833-rechte-zuviel-geliefert)*, the **sender can ask for the goods to be returned** according to § [BGB §812 (Herausgabeanspruch)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__812.html), because the recipient received them "without a legal basis". However, general opinion is that here is **no law that would require the recipient to notify the sender** - it is enough to wait for the sender to ask for the goods.

Also note that the above only applies if the delivery was *erroneous*, that is by mistake. If the seller *deliberately* sends the wrong article, or sends something without an order, then the recipient may keep it ([BGB §241a](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__241a.html)).

### Dissenting opinion on BGB §241

Some sources claim that the recipient may need to inform the sender because of [BGB §241](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__241.html), which says:

> (2) By its contents, an obligation may oblige each party to take
> account of the rights, legal interests and other interests of the
> other party.

This *could* be interpreted to require the recipient to protect the sender's rights by informing them. However, that would only apply in the context of an existing contract (such as a legitimate order), and it is unclear whether it is applicable here.

### Not a crime

At any rate, not informing the sender is at most a **civil wrong, and not a crime**. Keeping goods delivered in error could only become a crime if the recipient does something to obtain them - such as deliberatly causing the package to be delivered in error (*Betrug*, fraud), or taking possesion of a package that was delivered to a different or non-existent address (*Unterschlagung*, misappropriation, [StGB §246](https://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/246.html)).